# C# ASP.NET MVC : update view dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am learning C# using DotNetFiddle to code.

I have a web with a bunch of radio buttons and when I click them I want to update the view, for example: delete one button.

Also I need to do the delete logic in the backend and from the view I have to call a POST method to pass data.

So I'm trying to call the POST method with ajax and return `RedirectToAction` to display the new view, but somehow is not working.

You can check and test my current code here: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Bb9qp)

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public SampleViewModel sampleViewModel = new SampleViewModel();
        
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            return View(sampleViewModel);
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateList(string id)
        {
            sampleViewModel.deleteElement();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {       
        public List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"} ;
    }
}
```

View

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            
            <br></br>
            <ul>
            @foreach (var c in Model.arr)
            {
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="option" id="@c">@c
                </li>
            }
            </ul>
            
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
                $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
                    var elemId = $(this).attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="UpdateList", controller="Home"})',
                        data: { id : elemId },
                        type: "POST"
                    });     
                });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is not working because you are not actually passing the id to your delete method.  So it loads the full loop every time.

Comment: @Greg The delete method doesn't have any params, so I don't have to pass the Id

Comment: @mason Thanks for the suggestion, now I'm going to add it.

Comment: @Kaido but how do you know what delete?  You also redirect to a new creation of your model.

Comment: @Greg It is an exmaple, I don't care if it has no logic I only want the view to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've edited your Fiddle into this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zQq3aR

It does exactly what I describe below in the original answer, but uses the main view. Note that this is NOT what I would recommmend... we're rendering the entire view again, and then replacing the *entire* page contents with the new content, but I'm not too familiar with DotNetFiddle and don't know how to add more views (can you?).

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostToMe(string id)
{
    // TODO: Do some stuff here, then return the updated view
    
    return ButRenderMe(id);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ButRenderMe(string id)
{
    // Remove some content from the model
    sampleViewModel.arr = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "all of the above" };
    
    return View(sampleViewModel);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="PostToMe", controller="Home"})',
    data: { id : elemId },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        document.open();
        document.write(data);
        document.close();
    }
});
```

The better way to do this in a normal MVC project would be to have a PartialView used for rendering the content you want to replace... in this case the list. In your "update" action you would update your data, and then re-render just that PartialView and return it.  Then replace just that section with the new content.

With the code above, from my Fiddle, we may as well be making a normal page post instead of an AJAX call.

There are a lot of factors here, but hopefully this helps.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

So this is a bit confusing, given that your question doesn't match your code in either the DotNetFiddle or the question itself, but let's see if this helps.

I'm pretty sure that returning a RedirectToAction Result doesn't return the content from the other action your redirecting to. I think in this case, since it's an AJAX request, MVC knows that this isn't the proper usage, and returns a 200 OK status with the following example content. So with this Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RedirectMe()
{
    return RedirectToAction("UpdateList");
}
```

We get this Response:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/MvcPageAction/d5a71d77-e4c6-4b4c-a400-4543b1a9f897/Home/UpdateList">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

So again, I don't think that will work the way you want.

I *think* what you want is to *Render* the other action, and return that content back. And that should be as simple as calling that other action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostToMe(string id)
{
    return ButRenderMe(id);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ButRenderMe(string id)
{
    return Content("Test");
}
```

That returns the content "test". I think that you should be able to render a normal view in that other action if you want.

I looked at your DotNetFiddle as well...

In your DotNetFiddle your JavaScript is calling into `UpdateList` which doesn't seem to exist... not sure why it would even return a 200 OK... The Actions you have are Index and UpdateFlights. If you open the F12 Developer Tools in Chrome you should see that the POST returns no Content.

So I added a Controller Action called `UpdateList`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateList(string id)
{
    sampleViewModel.deleteElement();
    return Content("Test");
}
```

And I can see that "test" is returned as the Response content in the F12 Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't have UpdateList due to a typo, now It's correct. I tried what you suggest what It doesn't work, the buttons are not getting deleted. What I want, in other words, is update the current view dynamically by clicking a button but the delete logic has to be in the backend.

Comment: @Kaido I've updated the answer with my own Fiddle and some more info.